# Pick daily data via SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem, I'm trying to make a sum of a daily data from a specific table and column

```
 <?php
 $query = "SELECT (SELECT SUM(totaldeplata) FROM vanzari WHERE 
 MONTH(datainregistrarii) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())) + (SELECT SUM(totaldeplata) 
 FROM players WHERE MONTH(datainregistrarii) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())) as result";
 $query_run = mysql_query($query);
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run); 
 $sum = $row['result'];
 echo "sum of two different column from two tables : "+ $sum;
 ?>
```

This php query pick the monthly data and make a sum of it, it works, but I want to be able to make also a sum of daily data.

Any idea how?

Comment: What's the output when using the DAY() function?

Comment: Obligatory `mysql` functions are deprecated and removed as of 7.0. Please switch over to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: if i use DAY() sometimes it display what i need and sometimes wont!